# How to clear all selections in a wxListBox (with wxLB_MULTIPLE)?

Tags: c++, listbox, selection, wxwidgets

**How can I clear all selections in a wxListBox which has the style `wxLB_MULTIPLE`?**

Neither [wxControlWithItems::SetSelection()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxcontrolwithitems.html#wxcontrolwithitemssetselection) nor [wxControlWIthItems::SetStringSelection()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxcontrolwithitems.html#wxcontrolwithitemssetstringselection) work.
They only select the passed item but they do not deselect any other items as said in the documentation:

> Note that this does not cause any command events to be emitted nor
>   does it deselect any other items in the controls which support
>   multiple selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Platform independent method

As SteveL mentioned, you have to use [`wxListBox::GetSelections()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html#abe7c5010843f2b3522036588b5298427) and [`wxListBox::Deselect()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html#a892bf1c85f1ede9c22143cbb9fc22217) in a loop:

```
wxArrayInt selections;
int count = m_listBox->GetSelections(selections);

for ( int i=0; i<count; i++ )
{
  m_listBox->Deselect(selections[i]);
}
```

### ListBox_SetSel macro for Windows systems

You can use the macro [ListBox_SetSel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows API.

For this function, you have to include `Windowsx.h` and `wx/msw/winundef.h`, of course:

```
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include <wx/msw/winundef.h>

// ...
HWND hListBox = (HWND)m_listBox->GetHandle();
ListBox_SetSel(hListBox, false, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [wxListBox::GetSelections](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html#abe7c5010843f2b3522036588b5298427)
 followed by [wxListBox::Deselect](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html#a892bf1c85f1ede9c22143cbb9fc22217) as there is no deselect all method.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I found `wxListBox::DeselectAll()` (it was in the same way implemented as you said) in `common\listctrlcmn.cpp` in an **older wxWidgets 2.8 version**. But after an update I haven't found it anymore! Anyway I found an easier method for Windows systems -> see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

m_listBox->Clear();
this method work for me